# How can I get Serena to leave me alone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to have a Steward, but I currently have Serena. If I ask her to leave she won't go. I tried the mission to get Auriel's Bow but I could not doing since I couldn't find the place. Since I was stuck. So I gave up and went purchased land for a house. I want a Steward but Serena won't leave me alone. How can I fix this???!

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Good point, I guess I was just clarifying his issue when I really could have just answered the question -_-

Answer (score 4):

You are asking her to leave during quests where she is a vital follower and she is quest-related. That's probably why she won't leave your side. Just finish all of the main quests and then tell her to leave.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug.  Here is how you fix it:

1. Open the console by pressing ~
2. Right click on Serana OR type prid 02002b74 and hit enter to select Serana
3. Type Setpqv DLC1NPCMentalModel IsFollowing_var False
4. Hit enter key